# C++ - Can't Open File in XCode

Tags: c++, xcode, file-io

I have a main function which performs a few functions, notably calling two functions defined previously:

```
Student* readStudentsFromFile(string filename, int num) {
ifstream studentsStream;
studentsStream.open(filename.c_str());
if (!studentsStream.is_open()) {
    cerr << "Couldn't open the file " << filename << endl;
    return NULL;
}
// create a new array of students with size 'num'
Student* students = new Student[num];
string name, school, sid;
int id;
// read student records from file
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    getline(studentsStream, name, ',');
    getline(studentsStream, sid, ',');
    getline(studentsStream, school);
    istringstream idConv(sid);
    idConv >> id;
    // create a student object from the record and store it in the array
    students[i] = Student(id, name, school);
}
studentsStream.close();
return students;
}
```

Here is the main function:

```
int main() {

const int UC_SIZE = 10;
const int SMC_SIZE = 5;
const int SMC_UC_GRADS_SIZE = 2;
Student* uc = readStudentsFromFile("sample_uc_students.txt", UC_SIZE);
Student* smc = readStudentsFromFile("sample_smc_grads.txt", SMC_SIZE);
//const int UC_SIZE = 350000;
//const int SMC_SIZE = 75000;
//const int SMC_UC_GRADS_SIZE = 25000;
//Student* uc = readStudentsFromFile("uc_students.txt", UC_SIZE);
//Student* smc = readStudentsFromFile("smc_grads.txt", SMC_SIZE);

// Rough timing
time_t start, end;

time(&start);
Student* common1 = findCommonStudents1(uc, UC_SIZE, smc, SMC_SIZE,
                                       SMC_UC_GRADS_SIZE);
time(&end);
cout << "Using linear search it took " << difftime(end, start) << " seconds."
<< endl;


sort(common1, common1 + SMC_UC_GRADS_SIZE);
writeStudentsToFile(common1, SMC_UC_GRADS_SIZE, "smc_grads_at_uc_1.txt");

time(&start);
Student* common2 = findCommonStudents2(uc, UC_SIZE, smc, SMC_SIZE,
                                       SMC_UC_GRADS_SIZE);
time(&end);
cout << "Using binary search it took " << difftime(end, start)
<< " seconds." << endl;

sort(common2, common2 + SMC_UC_GRADS_SIZE);
writeStudentsToFile(common2, SMC_UC_GRADS_SIZE, "smc_grads_at_uc_2.txt");

delete[] smc;
delete[] uc;
delete[] common1;
delete[] common2;
return 0; }
```

Xcode is compiling, but I get an error message saying that "
Couldn't open the file sample_uc_students.txt
Couldn't open the file sample_smc_grads.txt
(lldb) "

These files are in the same directory as this file so I don't understand what is happening. Here is a picture just for confirmation:

[image]

Comment: Usually this means that when you run the program, the current directory isn't the one you expected. Try putting the files somewhere you can give the full path to.

Comment: Where should this be? I cannot change the path to the full path...

Comment: Maybe I need to change settings in xcode (I do not know how to do this in xcode 6)